# VSCode test explorer stops discovering tests when I add an import to python code file

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

This python code file works perfectly. But when I add either of the commented imports, the vscode test feature gives "No tests discovered, please check the configuration settings for the tests." No other errors.

```
# import boto3
# import pymysql
import decimal
import datetime

def increment(x):
    return x + 1
def decrement(x):
    return x - 1
```

What is it that I don't understand about imports and the test feature that explains why these would break the test explorer?